# Mmenu - scroll to element not working

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I have implemented [Mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) and I would like to add a function to scroll down to the current selected element - a li element with the class name ".current-page".

I have added

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".current-page").offset().top }, 1500);`

to the Mmenu code - see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhta5ux7/17/).
However, it's not working. The page is not scrolling.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. Menu is closed by default

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be triggered only when the menu is open. I found this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/p9ynx8wc/, but it scrolls to an anchor in the content area.

How can I make it work with the menu items? I found info on Mmenu's api: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/api.html, but I'm not sure how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an undocumented api option for the Mmenu, so I ended up doing something like this:

```
var api = $('#menu').data('mmenu');
api.bind('opened', function() {
    if ($(".current-page").length) {
        var selected = $(".current-page");
        selected[0].scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example to use of animation with `scrollTop`. It doesn't solve your problem but I hope it's good to help you start.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('.demo').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.demo')[0].scrollHeight
  }, 1500)
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto  
}
#content {
    height: 800px;
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
<button>Scroll down</button>
```